# ARC conversion issue with handleSearchForTerm delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

since converting to ARC (automatically) i have noticed with my uisearchviewcontroller delegate an issue somewhere (i think in the first if statement below). It was changed as a result but either way my app crashes when i try to perform a search:

The current code:

```
 [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

if ([self searchResults] == nil)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self setSearchResults:array];
    array = nil;
}

[[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
{
    for (KABrand *currentBrand in [self brands])
    {
        if ([currentBrand.name rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if (![searchResults containsObject:currentBrand])
                [[self searchResults] addObject:currentBrand];
        }
    }
}
```

The previous code:

```
- (void)handleSearchForTerm:(NSString *)searchTerm
{
   [self setSavedSearchTerm:searchTerm];

if ([self searchResults] == nil)
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self setSearchResults:array];
    [array release], array = nil;
}

[[self searchResults] removeAllObjects];

if ([[self savedSearchTerm] length] != 0)
{
    for (KABrand *currentBrand in [self brands])
    {
        if ([currentBrand.name rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch].location != NSNotFound)
        {
            if (![searchResults containsObject:currentBrand])
                [[self searchResults] addObject:currentBrand];
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thanks for your help in advance!

Thanks guys

Comment: I don't think you need the `array = nil;` line anymore under ARC; the compiler should be taking care of that when the variable goes out of scope. I'm not sure if that'll help the issue, though…

Comment: I thought in ARC setting a property of strong to nil is fine. but that wouldnt be the issue anyway :(

Comment: `array` here isn't actually the property, though; it's just pointing to the array that you set the property to. (It won't make a difference in execution, though, you're right.)

Comment: Good point still getting to grasps with ARC but thanks. Duly noted the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one potential problem:  `-rangeOfString:options:`   may return an NSNotFound. But you are checking if the `range.location != NSNotFound`.

If is if the return value of `-rangeOfString:options:` is NSNotFound, your if statement becomes `NSNotFound.location != NSNotFound`. I don't believe that's allowed.

Comment: not sure what you are saying mate but i dont think thats an issue as was working before anyway...

Comment: you are checking if the location property of an NSRange not equal to NSNotFound. That will never be the case. Your statement should read ` if ([currentBrand.name rangeOfString:searchTerm options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch]!= NSNotFound)`  There is now way your code would have worked as written before. The if statement would always been true.